# Azure App Service Connection String Not Working

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-string

I am working on an asp.net core web api project and its hosted on azure app service. What I'm trying is to put my cosmos db connection string in app service connection string. I added a document db type connection string but when I'm calling it, it wont get read.

[image]

I tried this,

```
CosmosDBAccountPrimaryKey = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DOCDBCONNSTR_COSMOSDBCONNSTR");
```

this also,

```
CosmosDBAccountPrimaryKey = _configuration.GetConnectionString("COSMOSDBCONNSTR");
```

But none worked. For just checking i tried to put the connection string in app setting variables and tried this,

```
CosmosDBAccountPrimaryKey = _configuration["COSMOSDBCONNSTR"];
```

This worked but when I'm calling from connection string, its not working.

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78131381/19648279) for the same issue.

Comment: You need to add .AddEnvironmentVariables and retrieve the key.

Comment: I just changed the connection string type to custom and it worked before it was set to document

Comment: Irrespective of Type you can retrieve it as mentioned in the above link

Comment: @wasihyder It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `Type` of connection string when creating it in app service. I was setting its type to `Document DB` which was not working. But when I set it up to `Custom` then it started working