# How to override appsettings.json values in Azure app service for an application deployed in Virtual path

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-appservice, asp.net-core-8

I have a .NET 8 application deployed to the Azure app service as a Virtual application along with another application in the root folder.

I was able to overwrite the application settings for the root application but not to the virtual application.

I was not able to find any documentation related to this.

Comment: After testing , I also can overwrite the application settings for virtual application. [Here is the test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um5dQ.png).

Comment: Can you please share your appsetings.json  file

Comment: What is the version of the root application?

Comment: Even I am able to override the value of Virtual App.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/ztVfwav.png).It will be easy to find out your issue if you share your local appsettings and the Azure App Settings of your Child App(Virtual path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to override the application settings of both Root and Virtual App.

***Virtual Path:***

[image]

- I haven't done any changes in the code.

***Environment Variables:***

[image]

- Try to retrieve the settings in `.cshtml` file.

***Root Application:***

```cs
@inject IConfiguration myconfig;
<h3>@myconfig["ParentSetting"]</h3>
```

[image]

***Child App:***

```cs
@inject IConfiguration myconfig;
 <h3>@myconfig["ChildSetting"]</h3>
 <h3>@myconfig["ParentSetting"]</h3>
```

[image]

> I was not able to find any documentation related to this.

There is no such documentation related to override Virtual App Settings.

- You can refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74948250/19648279) on how to deploy and work with Virtual Apps.
- Make sure you haven't set environment as Development in `Web.config`(if you have any) or in deployed `appsettings.json` file.
- Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78131381/19648279) to override `appsettings.json` for the Azure App Service.